# initializing pending intent crashes activity (the program stops)

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I am creating an alarm clock. I've followed several examples, but none of them helped. When I delete the pendingIntent line activity works properly.

```
package com.example.push_upalarmemptygit;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class SetAlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_alarm);

         context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0); //this is incorrect?

       findViewById(R.id.setExact).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              setExact();
           }
       });


    }

    public void setExact() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);


        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

I am following these guidelines from:
https://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android-using-alarmmanager/
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: "crashes activity (the program stops)" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash. I cover this process in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Answer (score 0):

Adding immutable flag solved the case.

```
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, pendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```